# Will the Sunlight's TransparencyData state campaign finance contributions every be updated again?

Tags: sunlight-foundation

Although the bulk data download page shows a state file for 2014, its is basically empty

http://data.influenceexplorer.com/bulk/

Does anyone know if there are plans to maintain and update TransparencyData?  Will they update to use NIMSP new id system?   We are trying to decided if we need to entirely abandon it and rewrite our backend switch back to NIMSP.

Comment: thanks albert, I contacted via the form, they responded, but answer was somewhat evasive: https://getsatisfaction.com/sunlightfoundation/topics/will-the-sunlights-transparencydata-state-campaign-finance-contributions-be-updated-again

Answer (score 1):

With Labs no longer in existence, the answer is no, Influence Explorer will never be updated.
However, the [ProPublica's FEC Itemizer](https://projects.propublica.org/itemizer/) comes highly recommended as the best source for most of the data that lived in Influence Explorer.